# Axon Framework does not provide InjectionPoint for bean factory methods

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, axon

I'm writing my first Axon tutorials, and I'd like to provide `Logger` as a bean, so I can easily mock/spy it:

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Logger logger(InjectionPoint ip) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
}
```

I usually inject it in constructors like this:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class FoodOrderingController {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;
    private final QueryGateway queryGateway;
```

That works fine. However, when I want to inject it in aggregate handler, like

```
@CommandHandler
public void handle(DeselectProductCommand command, Logger logger) throws ProductDeselectionException {
```

In this scenario, I get the following exception (with no stacktrace):

```
2020-05-22 14:23:44.263  WARN 16680 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.example.axon.foodcart.coreapi.command.DeselectProductCommand' resulted in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException(Error creating bean with name 'logger' defined in class path resource [com/example/axon/foodcart/CoreConfig.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current InjectionPoint available for method 'logger' parameter 0)
```

Is it possible to inject a Logger bean in Axon Framework? Or do I have to go back to static loggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

The reason for that is likely how the `SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory` and it's `SpringBeanParameterResolver` are used to retrieve Spring beans to inject in message handling functions.

At the moment a message handling function like your `@CommandHandler public void handle(DeselectProductCommand ...)` is called. The `SpringBeanParameterResolver#resolveParameterValue` method will be called, which in turn calls the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#getBean(String)`. As you might have noticed there, it doesn't use *any* notion of an `InjectionPoint`.

Implementing this wouldn't be hard I believe. The `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#resolveDependency(DependencyDescriptor, String)` method would be sufficient at a quick glance (`DependencyDescriptor` is an implementation of `InjectionPoint`). Might be worth providing an issue on Axon's GitHub for this, or even better, a PR.

---

**Suggestions**

However, I do have another suggestion to achieve the same non-functional requirement of logging without injecting it in **every** message handling function.
To achieve this form of logging in an Axon application, you can go two ways:

1. Use `MessageHandlerInterceptor`s and `MessageDispatchInterceptor`s which log upon ingestion and handling of any message. Quick solution would be to use Axon's `LoggingInterceptor` for this, which implements both interfaces. From there, you would register it to every message dispatching and handling component (thus the `CommandBus`, `EventBus`, all `EventProcessor`s and the `QueryBus`).
2. Provide a `HandlerEnhancerDefintion` which wraps *every* message handling function with your logging logic. Providing a Bean for this should be sufficient for Axon to pick it up and automatically wrap all `@MessageHandler` annotated methods.

Doing either of these means you are not obstructing the logic of handling commands, events and queries, with the rather dull logic of logging.

---

That's my two cents, hope it helps Andre!